# Есть ли здесь уточнение и нужна ли указанная запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

81 В случае, если параметры, указанные в предоставленной документации, не противоречат требованиям НТД, данное оборудование успешно вводится в проект (,) обычно без внесения изменений в ПСД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Если убрать наречие "успешно"(его смысл не очень понятен), то обособлять оборот не нужно, так как он входит в  основное содержание сообщения:

"В случае если параметры, указанные в предоставленной документации, не противоречат требованиям НТД, данное оборудование  вводится в проект  обычно без внесения изменений в ПСД".

2) Если наречие оставить, то постановка запятой факультативна, но  оборот, стоящий  в конце предложения, также лучше не обособлять. Если у автора есть желание придать обороту уточняющий характер, то предложение можно изменить:

"В случае если параметры, указанные в предоставленной документации, не противоречат требованиям НТД, данное оборудование успешно вводится в проект, при этом  изменения в ПСД обычно не вносятся".

3) "В случае если" - составной союз, в начале предложения чаще не обособляется.